# How to find all the elements on a determined distance on a Binary Search Tree in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

Given the class BinarySearchTree, an implementation of the TAD Binary
SearchTree, using only references to the children of each node (_right, _left),
we are asked to implement a subclass of the class BinarySearchTree, which we
will call BST2, and which will include the following methods:

1. find_dist_k(self, n, k). This method receives two parameters n and k which
   are positive integers and will return a Python list containing all nodes that
   are at a distance k from the node whose element is n. The distance between
   two nodes is the number of links that must be traversed to get from one to
   the other. The direction of the links is not taken into account, i.e. the
   distance between node A and node B is the same as between node B and
   node A. If the parameter n is not found in the tree, the method will return an
   empty list.

Notice that we cannot use the self.parent.

This is the code I obtained after some research:

```
def find_dist_k(self, n: int, k: int) -> list:
    # Here your code
    result = []
    node = self.search(n)
    if node is None:
        return result
    if n < 0 or k < 0:
        print("parameters of the function must be positive")
    self._find_dist_k(node, k, result)
    return result

def _find_dist_k(self, node, k, result):
    if node is None:
        return
    if k == 0:
        result.append(node.elem)
    else:
        self._find_dist_k(node.left, k - 1, result)
        self._find_dist_k(node.right, k - 1, result)
```

It works perfectly. However, it only returns the elements that are down the element. Look at this example:
input_list_01 = [5, 12, 2, 1, 3, 9]
If I executed this function self.find_dist_k(5, 2), output = [1,3,9]
If I executed this function self.find_dist_k(3, 2), output = [], where it should be [5]

Any comments to fix this?

Comment: Why for the last example the expected output is [5] and not [1,5]? It seems to me that the node with value 1 is also at distance 2 from node 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example tree you have used looks like this:

```
         _5_
        /   \
       2     12
      / \   /
     1   3 9
```

When the input is node 3 with k=2, then not only should the solution return node 5, but also node 1 since that node is also 2 edges away from node 3.

The algorithm should trace back on the path it followed to the target node and retain how much distance is left to work with. So for the example, it should trace back from node 3 to node 2 and there visit the alternate subtree with k=0, since it already took 2 steps to get to the alternate subtree (with node 1).

Then it should trace back one step more (from node 2 to node 5), where it finds that the remaining distance is 0 and that node should be output.

This also means you cannot use `self.search`, as that method only returns the target node without any information about the *path* to that node. Instead implement a search-like algorithm, but use recursion, so the caller still has the parent node to work with. Then when the recursive call comes back, check how much distance is still available, and if any, collect the nodes at that depth in the sibling subtree.

NB: I didn't see how your BST implementation calls the root, but I will assume it has a `_root` attribute.

Here is a possible implementation:

```
    def find_dist_k(self, n: int, k: int) -> list:
        result = []

        def collect_depth_k(node, k):
            if node:
                if k == 0:
                    result.append(node.elem)
                elif k > 0:
                    collect_depth_k(node.left, k - 1)
                    collect_depth_k(node.right, k - 1)
        
        def recur_dist_k(node, k):
            if not node:  # n not found
                return -1
            if n == node.elem:
                # Found node: collect all descendants at depth k
                collect_depth_k(node, k)
            else:
                # Not yet found, continue search
                child, sibling = [node.left, node.right] if n < node.elem else [node.right, node.left]
                k = recur_dist_k(child, k)
                # If k < 0 then either the node was not found, or we are too far above it
                if k == 0: # we are at the right distance above the found node
                    result.append(node.elem)
                elif k > 0: # Check other subtree for children at remaining distance
                    collect_depth_k(sibling, k - 1)
            return k - 1  # Return how much distance is remaining for parent to work with
        
        recur_dist_k(self._root, k)
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting only elements "down" the input node because your recursion references `node.left` and `node.right` - which I assume are child elements

To account for nodes from the ancestor nodes - you'll separately need to add them -

```py
def _find_dist_k(self, node, k, result):
    # ... Your code goes here
    current_node = node
    for i in range(k):
        current_node = current_node.parent
    if i == k:
        result.append(current_node)
```